# Workaround for repeatedly call Response.Redirect and returns ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: asp.net

I have a legacy web application in ASP.NET that,

1. has an ID field to identify each case which is also the key
2. a page shows other attributes based on the value of ID
3. a button to calculate some values based on the above attributes

We have a scenario to update some attributes in backend, and user want to re-calculate all values for step (3) by just one-click.

As the code is not tidy for easily to implement such recalculate-all, we tried the following dirty approach,

1. click recalculate-all button
2. it redirects to the first case (using `Response.Redirect`)

   `http://server?recalc=Y&id=1`
3. it will re-calculate all values for the first case, and automatically redirect to next case

   `http://server?recalc=Y&id=2`
4. it will re-calculate all values for this case, repeat until to the last value

   `http://server?recalc=Y&id=LAST_VALUE`

But it returns **ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS** after about 20 iterations. Any workaround to bypass this limit?

Answer (score 0):

I use JavaScript embedded in ASP.NET as below and this works without error

```
Response.Write("<script language=javascript>window.open('xxxx', '_self');</script>")
```